# Assumption to interpret the data either Intersection probability or main sample probability

Tags: probability

[image]

In the question above the writer said 4.5% of all student attend to private collage which for me it means $P(C)$ while the write assumed it is the join probability between student went to private school and to collage $P(C\cap D)$

$D$ = went to private school

$D^c$ = didn't go to private school

saying $4.5\%$ of all students attend to private college means for me.

$P(D\cap C) + P(D^c \cap C)$ or $P(C)$

could you please clearify which term is correct here?

Comment: As I read it, there is clearly a mistake in the exercise and your understanding is correct. As it is now, $P(C)=4.5\%$ and not $P(C\mid D)=4.5\%$.